# Search and remove "00:00" values from each column

Tags: excel, vb.net, epplus

I am trying to get my codes to go through each DateTime column and search for cells that contain "00:00" as hours and minutes. If the value exists, remove 00:00 and only leave the date. For the cells that don't contain that value, leave the cells as they are. For example, if "3/22/2017 00:00", then format it to "3/22/2017". Otherwise, if "3/22/2017 09:16", leave it alone. Thank you in advance!

```
dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
dataGrid.DataBind()
ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dataGrid.DataSource, True)
Dim data = dataGrid.DataSource
Dim columnCount = data.Columns.Count
For i = 0 To columnCount - 1
    If data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
        If Not data.Columns(i).ToString.Contains("00:00") Then
            ws.Column(i + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
        Else
            ws.Column(i + 1).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I think your solution is ok, you just have to change the styles per cell, not per column in your inner `IF`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by:

1. Setting a default format for all `DateTime` *columns*
2. *Only* overriding the default format for values that meet your criteria.

Here's a simple helper method that handles multiple `DateTime` columns:

```
Sub SetDateTimeStyles(ByRef data As DataTable, ByRef ws As ExcelWorksheet)
    ' Track DateTime columns to override default column style
    Dim dateTimeColumns = New List(Of Integer)()

    ' Set column format
    Dim columnCount = data.Columns.Count
    For i = 0 To columnCount - 1
        If data.Columns(i).DataType Is GetType(DateTime) Then
            Dim epPlusColumn = i + 1
            ws.Column(epPlusColumn).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
            dateTimeColumns.Add(epPlusColumn)
        End If
    Next

    ' Header row exists; set to 1 if no header row
    Dim rowOffset = 2
    Dim rowCount = data.Rows.Count

    ' Only set cell format when hour and minute are **both** zero
    For i = 0 To rowCount - 1
        For Each dateTimeColumn In dateTimeColumns
            Dim value As DateTime = data(i)(dateTimeColumn - 1)
            If value.Hour = 0 AndAlso value.Minute = 0 AndAlso value.Second = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(i + rowOffset, dateTimeColumn) _
                    .Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

And call it when creating the Excel file:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = dataSet.Tables(0)
dataGrid.DataBind()
ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromDataTable(dataGrid.DataSource, True)
Dim data As DataTable = dataGrid.DataSource
SetDateTimeStyles(data, ws)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello kuujinbo, thanks for your reply as well as taking the time to share your solution and insight. Your approach is more inline with what we're trying to do. We're borrowing your concept and going to customize it with what we have. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

For your solution to work, you would need to set the style on each individual cell.  This is an inefficient solution as a style would be created for each cell.  Is could be mitigated somewhat by defining two different styles and assigning those references to the cell as needed.

A simpler solution is use the [DataGridView.CellFormatting Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the format when the cell is painted.

Evidently, the DateTime values have a time component less than one minute because the default formatting would have yield the desired result if this was not the case.  The code below sets the format based on whether the time component is less than one minute.

```
Private Shared tsLimit As New TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) ' 1 minute
Private Shared dtType As Type = GetType(DateTime)

Private Sub dataGrid_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles dataGrid.CellFormatting
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast(dgv.DataSource, DataTable)
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim sourceColumn As DataColumn = dt.Columns.Item(dgv.Columns.Item(e.ColumnIndex).DataPropertyName)
        If sourceColumn IsNot Nothing AndAlso sourceColumn.DataType Is dtType AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not e.Value Is DBNull.Value Then
            Dim d As DateTime = CDate(e.Value)
            If d.TimeOfDay < tsLimit AndAlso d.Hour <> 0 Then
                e.CellStyle.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"
            Else
                e.CellStyle.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code could potentially convert a *datetime* of midnight plus a few seconds, to just a *date*. The exclusion of `00:00` is probably meant to handle *datetimes* entered with no date, or for instance sql *date* type. You are close, but I would bet the OP's logic was already good enough, and yours may introduce a bug.

Comment: @djv, good point about midnight edge case.  Easily handled by checking the date's hour component.  Code updated.

Comment: Hello TnTinMn, thanks for your reply as well as taking the time to share your solution and insight. The DataGridView.CellFormatting Event would never come to mind. I will give it a try and see how I can implement it.